Specifying path with space in MSVC linker .def file
I'm trying to feed MSVC linker with the following .def file:
EXPORTS
SomeExport=C:\Program Files\Directory\somedll.SomeExport @1

The objective is to compile a DLL containing a forwarded exported function that points to another DLL located in a path with a space in it. However, it seems MSVC linker does not allow paths with spaces, since parsing this .def file will throw the following error message:
 fatal error LNK1118: syntax error in the instruction 'Files\Directory\somedll.SomeExport

I've tried wrapping the forwarded dll path with double and triple quotes (and also removing the ordinal from the export definition) but I keep getting the same outcome.
Is there any way to achieve this using a .def file and the MSVC linker?

Try double quotes around the "filepath\filename.type"

@EvilTeach Already tried, It didn't work

You can only export by name, not full path.

@Luke of course you can export by full path, it is called a forwarded export. I'm looking for a way to do so but inserting a path with a space in it,

A forwarded export uses a name, not a full path.

A forwarded export uses a name only if you follow the public official documentation. But everybody knows that Windows' official documentation is incomplete. I've been using full path for forwarded exports for years, and I can ensure you that it works perfectly.
